# Overriding a Cufon Font

Tags: javascript, fonts, cufon

I'm trying to override the custom Cufon Font to be Arial.  I've also tried targeting the H3 by the id but I cannot override it because the linked JS file is needed for other custom pieces of the page.

Below is my example.

```
// This code is a linked js file I cannot alter
Cufon.replace(['h3'], {
    fontFamily: 'Filmotype LaSalle',
    hover: true
 });

// This code is my override code to try to make the my H3 Arial which isn't working.
Cufon.replace(['h3'], {
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    hover: true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Cufon actually replaces the H3 with different HTML. So doing another replace will not work at all. You will have to remove the Filmotype LaSalle font first.

Next to that, cufon needs a font file. It will not just randomly accept any default font. You will have to create a font file yourself: http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/